# Why can't roslaunch or rosrun find my executable?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a little package which sends commands from the keyboard to turtlesim.  The examples are rosbuild based and I'm trying to do it in hydro/catkin.

I've got it building and putting a binary in catkin_ws/install/lib/PROJECTNAME/    How do I specify in the .launch file that ROS should look in /install/lib/PROJECTNAME ??   If I copy the binary from /build/PROJECTNAME to /src/PROJECTNAME it runs.    Should I just copy it over every time?   There must be a better way!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154561/why-can%27t-roslaunch-or-rosrun-find-my-executable?/) by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you sourced the install space of your workspace before trying to launch the node? In general it should be working exactly as you want it to: No manual moving of files required.

PS: When you say "I've got it building and putting a binary in catkin_ws/install/lib/PROJECTNAME/ ", you are not moving that binary manualy, but with `catkin_make install`, right?

**Edit:** There are two different things. For one, you need source `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` before building your workspace with `catkin_make`. You do that in your .bashrc and that is ok.

After you built your package, you need to source the install or devel space of your workspace in order to use it. It is best that you have two terminal. One to build, and one to rosrun/roslaunch.

So after building your package, open a new terminal and execute `source catkin_ws/install/setup.bash`. Now in this terminal, rosrun/roslaunch should be able to find the node you compiled.

PS2: It is best to update your question with more details (use the "edit" function) rather than posting answers that do not actually answer your question.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on 2014-04-18**:
Many thanks for the newbie hand holding!!

**Comment by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on 2014-04-18**:
However, that procedure didn't work:
`~/Projects/Ros/catkin_ws$ !roslaunch roslaunch turtle_fsm turtle_fsm.launch  [turtle_fsm.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtle_fsm] nor is [turtle_fsm] a launch file name` 
(my package name is `turtle_fsm')

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-18**:
did you execute this in the shell after `source ~/Projects/Ros/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash`? Does the file `turtle_fsm.launch` exist inside your package?

**Comment by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on 2014-04-22**:
Thanks I'll try that.